# HTTP proxy for Appium in native apps?

Tags: appium, sniffing, browsermob

I was wondering if somebody has an idea what Java/Groovy library/tool to use for sniffing, recording and processing HTTP traffic of native apps when running Appium tests ? Does anybody has experience with Browser Mob for that specific case ? Thanks! Best, Daniel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853094/best-way-to-analyze-http-traffic-sent-by-my-java-code shall help you

Comment: Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes browsermob can be used used with native apps and selenium. We tried many other network sniffing proxies but browsermob works best for selenium.

Can be done in 3 simple steps(not so simple by the way).

1. Run browsermob from standalone server and get response as har in localhost
2. Write code to validate your output.
3. Call browsermob methods in your selenium code to call
4. Validate the response you got with code you have already written for validation.

Mostly validation involves parsing JSON files as most of https responses will be in JSON format.

- If you need help in any specific area of browsermob proxy or selenium or running feel free to ask me.

Comment: can you please share how to setup browsermob with appium ?
I created appium + android driver, all are running but har file still empty.
I want to catch traffic from my native app, I set on me device the browsermob certificate